# Extract lists of p-values for each regression coefficients (1104 linear regressions) with R

Tags: r, regression, p-value

I try to do 1104 linear regressions with the same model. My independent variable does not change. However, my dependant variable does. Indeed, I have 1104 dependent variables. I can only extract all the coefficients (intercepts included), t-stats and R-square stats. I would also like to extract all the p-values lists of each coefficients within the 1104 linear regressions. How to do that with an easy way ?

Here are my codes:

## run 1104 regressions for M1

```
bigtest<-as.data.frame(bigtest)

test <- lapply(135:1238, function(i) lm(bigtest[,i]~bigtest[,"rm"]))

reg_sq  <- sapply(1:length(test),function(i) summary(test[[i]])$r.squared)
#reg_sq

coefrm <- sapply(1:length(test),function(i)summary(test[[i]])$coefficients[2,1])
intercept <- sapply(1:length(test),function(i)summary(test[[i]])$coefficients[1,1])
#betas

tstatrm <- sapply(1:length(test),function(i)  summary(test[[i]])$coefficients[2,3])
tstatint <- sapply(1:length(test),function(i)  summary(test[[i]])$coefficients[1,3])
#tstat

m1 <- cbind(reg_sq,coefrm,intercept,tstatrm,tstatint)
resultsM1 <- as.data.frame(m1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a tidyverse solution in multiple parts, hopefully easier to read that way :-) I used `mtcars` as a play dataset with `mpg` as the invariant independent variable

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(broom)
library(tibble)

# first key change is let `broom::tidy` do the hard work

test2 <- lapply(2:10, function(i) broom::tidy(lm(mtcars[,i] ~ mtcars[,"mpg"])))
names(test2) <- names(mtcars[2:10])
basic_information <-
   map2_df(test2,
           names(test2),
           ~ mutate(.x, which_dependent = .y)) %>%
   mutate(term = ifelse(term == "(Intercept)", "Intercept", "mpg")) %>%
   select(which_dependent, everything())

basic_information
#> # A tibble: 18 x 6
#>    which_dependent term      estimate std.error statistic  p.value
#>    <chr>           <chr>        <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
#>  1 cyl             Intercept  11.3       0.593      19.0  2.87e-18
#>  2 cyl             mpg        -0.253     0.0283     -8.92 6.11e-10
#>  3 disp            Intercept 581.       41.7        13.9  1.26e-14
#>  4 disp            mpg       -17.4       1.99       -8.75 9.38e-10
#>  5 hp              Intercept 324.       27.4        11.8  8.25e-13
#>  6 hp              mpg        -8.83      1.31       -6.74 1.79e- 7
#>  7 drat            Intercept   2.38      0.248       9.59 1.20e-10
#>  8 drat            mpg         0.0604    0.0119      5.10 1.78e- 5
#>  9 wt              Intercept   6.05      0.309      19.6  1.20e-18
#> 10 wt              mpg        -0.141     0.0147     -9.56 1.29e-10
#> 11 qsec            Intercept  15.4       1.03       14.9  2.05e-15
#> 12 qsec            mpg         0.124     0.0492      2.53 1.71e- 2
#> 13 vs              Intercept  -0.678     0.239      -2.84 8.11e- 3
#> 14 vs              mpg         0.0555    0.0114      4.86 3.42e- 5
#> 15 am              Intercept  -0.591     0.253      -2.33 2.64e- 2
#> 16 am              mpg         0.0497    0.0121      4.11 2.85e- 4
#> 17 gear            Intercept   2.51      0.411       6.10 1.05e- 6
#> 18 gear            mpg         0.0588    0.0196      3.00 5.40e- 3
```

Just to change things up a bit... we'll use `map` to construct formula

```r
y <- 'mpg'
x <- names(mtcars[2:10])

models <- map(setNames(x, x),
              ~ lm(as.formula(paste(.x, y, sep="~")),
                   data=mtcars))

pvalues <-
   data.frame(rsquared = unlist(map(models, ~ summary(.)$r.squared)),
              RSE = unlist(map(models, ~ summary(.)$sigma))) %>%
   rownames_to_column(var = "which_dependent")

results <- full_join(basic_information, pvalues)

#> Joining, by = "which_dependent"
results
# A tibble: 18 x 8
   which_dependent term      estimate std.error statistic  p.value rsquared    RSE
   <chr>           <chr>        <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 cyl             Intercept  11.3       0.593      19.0  2.87e-18    0.726  0.950
 2 cyl             mpg        -0.253     0.0283     -8.92 6.11e-10    0.726  0.950
 3 disp            Intercept 581.       41.7        13.9  1.26e-14    0.718 66.9  
 4 disp            mpg       -17.4       1.99       -8.75 9.38e-10    0.718 66.9  
 5 hp              Intercept 324.       27.4        11.8  8.25e-13    0.602 43.9  
 6 hp              mpg        -8.83      1.31       -6.74 1.79e- 7    0.602 43.9  
 7 drat            Intercept   2.38      0.248       9.59 1.20e-10    0.464  0.398
 8 drat            mpg         0.0604    0.0119      5.10 1.78e- 5    0.464  0.398
 9 wt              Intercept   6.05      0.309      19.6  1.20e-18    0.753  0.494
10 wt              mpg        -0.141     0.0147     -9.56 1.29e-10    0.753  0.494
11 qsec            Intercept  15.4       1.03       14.9  2.05e-15    0.175  1.65 
12 qsec            mpg         0.124     0.0492      2.53 1.71e- 2    0.175  1.65 
13 vs              Intercept  -0.678     0.239      -2.84 8.11e- 3    0.441  0.383
14 vs              mpg         0.0555    0.0114      4.86 3.42e- 5    0.441  0.383
15 am              Intercept  -0.591     0.253      -2.33 2.64e- 2    0.360  0.406
16 am              mpg         0.0497    0.0121      4.11 2.85e- 4    0.360  0.406
17 gear            Intercept   2.51      0.411       6.10 1.05e- 6    0.231  0.658
18 gear            mpg         0.0588    0.0196      3.00 5.40e- 3    0.231  0.658
```

Comment: Thank you Chuck P !

Comment: If that meets your needs please mark the check mark for answered

Comment: Is there a way to display these p-values properly ? I mean per columns ? "Cyl disp hp draft...gear" (9 rows) and "Intercept mpg" (2 columns). Indeed, my goal is to compute means of p-values for all of my "intercept" and all of my "mpg"

Comment: Tell me more about "properly" I don't understand what you want...  As to deriving *"compute means of p-values for all of my "intercept" and all of my "mpg" "* that is trivial with the following code `results %>% group_by(term) %>% summarise(mean_p = mean(p.value))`

Comment: Are there columns you don't want?  To make it "wider" with one row per dependent variable and keep all the information we could `wide_results <- results %>% pivot_wider(names_from = term, values_from = estimate:p.value)
`  which goes from 18 rows and 7 columns to 9 rows and 11 columns the columns would be "which_dependent" "rsquared" "RSE" "estimate_Intercept" "estimate_mpg" "std.error_Intercept" "std.error_mpg" "statistic_Intercept" "statistic_mpg" "p.value_Intercept" "p.value_mpg"

Comment: ''' results %>% group_by(term) %>% summarise(mean_p = mean(p.value))''' helps me a lot to get the means. I don't have any error messages. However, when I have 11 independent variables in my model: ''' #MCFG1: rm zdy ztbl ztms zdfy rm_zdy rm_ztbl rm_ztms rm_zdfy contexte rm_contexte
....''' , I have errors messages => Error in model.frame.default(formula = as.formula(paste(.x, y1, y2, y3,  : 
  object is not a matrix. How can I fix that ?

Comment: No idea, haven't thought about it Your entire question was based on **one** invariant independent variable and 1104 different dependents.  You've just changed things from the very beginning

Comment: Do you have multiple independents that are invariant?  For example the same three or four every time?  Making that happen is possible I just want to understand the requirement?

Comment: Actually, I have the same 11 invariant independents. I've just posted a new question here :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63959337/extract-lists-of-coefficients-and-p-values-for-multiple-invariant-independent-va

Answer (score 2):

`sapply(test, function(i) summary(i)$coefficients[-1, 4])` will get you the p-values. Note, I'm assuming you don't need the intercept. Also the sapply can be written a bit more cleanly that what you've been using.

Here's a small example:

```
y <- c(1.03, 2.05, 2.91, 4.07)
x1 <- c(2.1, 4.3, 5.8, 7.9)
x2 <- c(43, 17, 11, 7)
x3 <- c(5.1, 6.1, 5.5, 6.8)
df <- data.frame(y, x1, x2, x3)

# Fit models
fit <- lapply(df[,-1], function(x) lm(df$y~x))

# Extract pvalues with intercept
pval <- sapply(fit, function(x) summary(x)$coefficients[,4])
pval 


Output: 
                    x1         x2        x3
(Intercept) 0.311515551 0.02163118 0.3022066
x           0.001185388 0.09842442 0.1855516


# Without intercept
pval2 <- sapply(fit, function(x) summary(x)$coefficients[-1,4])
pval2 

Output:
        x1          x2          x3 
0.001185388 0.098424425 0.185551567
```